# Cannot save image in an Android app

Tags: android, api, camera

I am working on an app that uses other camera apps to take a picture. I can successfully launch another camera app but I don't see the picture is saved into my desired folder. Here is my code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage); 
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I expected MyImages folder will be created but I couldn't find it on my device.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you set the permission in manifest.xml?  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with this permission in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```